# How to add onto custom contact fields using the import wizard

Tags: data-import-wizard

I am storing invoice information in a large custom text field inside my contacts in SF. When I import my invoicing CSV file to my contacts, it has a cell that is invoice information... such as "6/11/15 +$500.00 for Fall Tuition". This will load into my custom invoice field in my contact. However, is there a way that when there is another transaction imported into SF that it won't have to rewrite what is in the custom invoice field, but rather just add onto it? I want to keep track of every single transaction that affects their account balance under their contact information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this using the import wizard only. There are several ways to accomplish this. The general way you'll do it is to get an extract of your contacts, concatenate the old value with whatever your adding to it in Excel or another program, and then update that value.

You should strongly consider making a custom object to store your invoice information.

Comment: Are there any ways to do this directly inside Salesforce? I am trying to limit the amount of manual work done, all while centralizing any labor into salesforce.

I have a custom object to store logs, but I wanted the ease of access of useful information under each contact. I am brand new to Salesforce, so any recommendations help.

Thanks again

Comment: I agree you should be using an object for this. This is a pretty strange use case for a single field  and there will be many benefits in the long run to using an object instead of what is effectively a free text field

Comment: @Austin Might be possible with an Apex trigger. This is not a recommended solution.